# how to get the best Best Fit Parameters of a special-function nonlinear fitting and how to find a good starting value?

Tags: plotting, fitting, special-functions

```
data1 = {{0, 10}, {0.1, 4.21}, {0.2, 5.49}, {0.3, 6.52}, 
    {0.4, 4.92}, {0.5, 3.79}, {0.6, 1.53}, {0.7, 1.04}, 
    {0.8, 0.34}, {0.9, 0.21}, {1, 0}}; 
model1 = Sum[(-20/(k*Pi))*MittagLefflerE[\[Beta], 
       (-d)*k^2*Pi^2*149^\[Beta]]*Sin[k*Pi*x], {k, 1, 20}] + 10 - 
    10*x; 
M1 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, model1, 
    {{\[Beta], 0.5}, {d, 0.005}}, x]; 
M1["BestFitParameters"]
M1["RSquared"]
Show[{ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Black], 
   Plot[Normal[M1], {x, data1[[1,1]], data1[[-1,1]]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

my code is above, I want to use the special-function form to fit the listed data.
I have tried many initial values for the fitting parameters, but which seems don't work.
The range for the parameters are β∈(0,1], d>0.

Comment: To start, you could include the parameter constraints into `NonlinearModelFit`: `NonlinearModelFit[data1, {model1, 0 < \[Beta] < 1, d > 0}, {{\[Beta], 0.5}, {d, 0.005}}, x]`. That at least gets rid of the multiple errors and warnings in your code. However, you are the best person to guess better starting values for your own model with your own data, based on physical constraints and your knowledge of the underlying physical system.

Comment: I ge: `{\[Beta] -> 0.00159905, d -> 0.183453}`  what fits the data rather badly. Is you model correct?

Comment: After adding in the constraints (as suggested by @MacroB), you get a fit.  But when you look at `M1["ParameterTable"]` you see huge standard errors and `M1["CorrelationMatrix"]` is estimated to be `{{1,1},{1,1}}` which suggests that the estimators of $\beta$ and $d$ are perfectly correlated.  In short, your model is too complicated for the available data.  And on top of that it doesn't look like a good fit.  (Kind of like a restaurant review:  the food was bad and the portions too small.)

Comment: I don't think that your first and last data point should counted as data because the model  obtains those exact values when $x=0$ and $x=1$ no matter what the values of $\beta$ and $d$ are.

Answer (score 4):

If one fits the model using the restrictions you believe are true, the estimated standard errors are huge and the parameter estimators are almost perfectly negatively correlated.

```
data1 = {{0, 10}, {0.1, 4.21}, {0.2, 5.49}, {0.3, 6.52}, {0.4, 4.92}, {0.5, 3.79},
   {0.6, 1.53}, {0.7, 1.04}, {0.8, 0.34}, {0.9, 0.21}, {1, 0}};
model1 = Sum[(-20/(k*Pi))*MittagLefflerE[β, (-d)*k^2*Pi^2*149^β] Sin[k*Pi*x], {k, 1, 20}] + 
  10 - 10*x;
M1 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, {model1, 0 < β < 1 && d > 0}, {{β, 0.5}, {d, 0.005}}, x];
M1["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

```
M1["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Correlation matrix]

This means that widely different sets of values of $\beta$ and $d$ can result in near identical predictions.  (This doesn't mean the predictions are necessarily bad but rather you just can't settle on individual estimates of $\beta$ and $d$.)

Consider fixing values of $\beta$ and then finding the best fits for $d$.  We end up with very different estimates of $d$ but nearly the same predictions.

```
(* Set β to 0.6 *)
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, {model1 /. β -> 0.6, d > 0}, {{d, 0.01}}, x];
nlm1["BestFitParameters"]
(* {d -> 0.00633013} *)

(* Set β to 0.1 *)
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, {model1 /. β -> 0.1, d > 0}, {{d, 0.1}}, x];
nlm2["BestFitParameters"]
(* {d -> 0.105734} *)

Show[Plot[{nlm1[x], nlm2[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> {"β = 0.6, d = 0.00633", "β = 0.1, d = 0.1057"}],
 ListPlot[data1]]
```

[image: Data and two fits]

In short, if you really want to know the values of $\beta$ and $d$, you can't do so with this data/model combination.  The predictions are consistent no matter what values of $\beta$ and $d$ you end up with as high values of $\beta$ will be compensated for with lower values of $d$ (and vice versa).

Finally, the first and last observations can be dropped as they do not influence the estimation of $\beta$ and $d$ because the model ends up with those values no matter the values of $\beta$ and $d$.

***Addition:***

As this question appears likely to be closed in the very near future, here is something else that suggests that the near perfect correlation between the estimators of $\beta$ and $d$ causes great difficulties in interpreting the coefficients.  With the results `nlm1` that fixes $\beta$ at 0.6 we see that the standard error of the estimator of $d$ is much, much smaller:

```
nlm1["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table for nlm1]